# where to install a cumulative update for appfabric

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

I have a web server which hosts a web application which reference the appfabric client DLL's in order to use caching.

In addition, I have a server which is the caching host for appfaric.

1) when I install the cumulative updates for appfabric, do I need to install them on both the host server and the web server?

2) Is it enough to install cumulative update 5? (and not all previous updates). I read that Microsoft said its enough, but it wasn't clear.

3) I found out about appfabric cumulative updates by mistake, how can I be notified or where can I check regularly if there is a new update for appfabric(its very important for my production environment, since I do an extensive use of appfabric caching).

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I recommend to install it on both hosts, the CU5 contains updates for web server parts and cache cluster (first use a test environment and backup your production system before you change it)
2. The answer is yes, you always just need the latest version, therefore they call it cumulative update.
3. The update notification is really poor, usually you find it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/).